# I want my desktop application to connect to a Website database

Tags: vb.net

I want my desktop application to connect to a Website database (MySQL Database is used).

Will I use the website URL, e.g., http://www.orangecalltaxi.in as my host?

1. Through webservice to connect to the above website
2. In the Above mysqlDatabase(website) there was a table "Table1"
3. I want to get the "Table1" values and save those values into my oracleDatabase "table2"

I have no idea about this issue

Somebody to help on this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have your client either connect directly with database that holds Table1 or if a webservice is available and it returns the information you require then you can use that. Using the website URL will not help

Comment: how to use webservices in deskstop application to retrieve those mysqldatabase table  of values in my application.can you give some idea about this?

Comment: Try a search engine and search for consuming webservice... do some homework before asking questions. You will be able to ask better consise questions and get answers if you can show you have done research.